# How to set up Dropbox on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, 9.10, dropbox

I've installed Dropbox on Ubuntu Server 9.10 using [these instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-dropbox-in-ubuntu-9-10karmic9-04jaunty8-10intrepid8-04hardy.html), however I am struggling to find out what to do next. Other help pages are related to those with a GUI.

Running `dropbox status` returns: `Dropbox isn't responding!`

How do I login to my existing Dropbox account and choose a folder for it to start using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox has instructions for a text-based Linux install [here](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall).

The short version is that the first time you run the dropboxd daemon, it will warn that it's not linked to an account and give you a URL to visit in order to link it. By default, it will use ~/Dropbox as the Dropbox folder, but there's a [Python script](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) you can download to change it.

Comment: I've already installed it as I said, I'm asking how to set it up. Surely I need to fill in the email and password for the account somewhere?

Comment: You visit the link it gives you in a web browser (which can be on a different machine) that's already logged into Dropbox, and it will then associate the new install with that account.